# Ideal is proper iff quotient non-trivial

Tags: ring-theory

This is in my lecture notes and I don't see why we need the commutative condition here:

Suppose $R$ is a commutative ring and $I$ is an ideal in $R$. Then $I$ is proper if and only if $R/I$ is non-trivial.

I think if $I$ is not proper, that is, $I=R$, then $R/I$ is trivial; and if $R/I$ is trivial, then $I$ has to be the entire $R$?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You do not need commutativity for this.

Comment: You should not always expect authors to produce assertions that use minimal assumptions. Sometimes they do not want to do so.

Comment: Indeed, to expand on @Randall’s comment, the claim is really a statement about the underlying additive group structure: has nothing to do with multiplication at all.